# How to calculate distance from top of container until end of window via CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML layout with a few elements, and below a scrollable div container.

I don't know the size of `unknown-height` because the elements are generated dynamically, is there a simple way to make the div container scrollable, but set the height not exceeding the bottom of the window?

```css
.scrollbar {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px) !important;
}
```

```html
<p id="unknown-height">
  foo
</p>
<input type="text" />
<div class="scrollbar">
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Short answer: no. SASS is a CSS preprocessor and converts to CSS, so really, you're asking if CSS is content height aware. If you add your HTML for your layout along with relevant CSS to create a minimal example, we might be able to offer other solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question to a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

**parent container**

- use flexbox on container,
- set height
- flex-orientation to restore a vertical flow. -> in this way all child element will fill up the height of the container
- add overflow hidden to hide stuff that would normally need more space

**scrolling child**

- set overflow scroll to you child element

**NB** I added border colors to check easly the final result.

```css
.your-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.scrollbar {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-container">
  <p id="unknown-height">
    foo
  </p>
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="scrollbar">
  scrollbar
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Foo</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is almost what I need. Unfortunately my example is a little bit more complex. In my case the blue and red border are where they are supposed to be, but the div doesn't scroll anymore, despite a computed overflow-y. Do you know what I can look for that prevents the div from being scrollable?

Comment: First I woul remove the overflow of the parent to check what's happening inside the child. Then maybe set display: block to the child,it should have "solidity" to scroll.